# possible already open file error; halted

Tags: java

So, when I run this, I get no exceptions, but the execution halts. I entered a few lines of code to see where the hault is coming from. On initial execution, it creates a file in the path given in the Customer class. Once I do one of the actions, it doesn't let me go past the first debugging line. Ideas?

Heres the application:
package javaapplication18.pkg3;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication183 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static boolean keepGoing = true;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Customer Maintenance application");
    //keepGoing = true;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (keepGoing){
        displayMenu();
        String userChoice = getRequiredString("Enter a command: ", sc);
        System.out.println("DEBUG LINE 1");


        CustomerTextFile textFile = new CustomerTextFile();
        System.out.println("DEBUG LINE 2");
        performAction(userChoice, textFile);
        System.out.println("DEBUG LINE 3");

    }
    // TODO code application logic here
}

public static void displayMenu() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("COMMAND MENU");
    System.out.println("list    - List all customers");
    System.out.println("add     - Add a customer");
    System.out.println("del     - Delete a customer");
    System.out.println("help    - Show this menu");
    System.out.println("exit    - Exit this application");
    System.out.println();
}



public static void performAction(String choice, CustomerTextFile textFile){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    switch (choice.toLowerCase()) {
        case "list":    
            //action
            ArrayList<Customer> currentList = textFile.getCustomers();
            for (Customer c : currentList) {
                System.out.print(c.getEmail() + "\t");
                System.out.print(c.getFirstName() + "\t");
                System.out.println(c.getLastName());
                }
            break;
        case "add":
            String email = getRequiredString("Enter customer email address:", sc);
            String firstName = getRequiredString("Enter first name:", sc);
            String lastName = getRequiredString("Enter last name:", sc);
            Customer c = new Customer(email, firstName, lastName);
            textFile.addCustomer(c);
            System.out.println(firstName + lastName + " was added to the database.");
            break;
        case "del":

            String deleteUserByEmail = getRequiredString("Enter customer email to delete:", sc);
            Customer delCustomer = textFile.getCustomer(deleteUserByEmail);
            textFile.deleteCustomer(delCustomer);
            break;
        case "help":
            //displayMenu();
            break;
        case "exit":
           keepGoing = false;//exit();
           break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You entereed something not in the list. Please try again.");
            System.out.println();
    }
}


public static boolean exit(){
    System.out.println("Exit");
    return false;
    }

public static String getRequiredString(String prompt, Scanner sc) {
String s = "";
boolean isValid = false;
while (isValid == false) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    s = sc.nextLine();
            if (s.equals("")) 
                System.out.println("Error! This entry is required. Try again.");
            else 
                isValid = true;
            }
    return s;
}

}
```

Here is the CustomerTextFile class:

```
package javaapplication18.pkg3;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomerTextFile implements CustomerDAO{
    private ArrayList<Customer> customers = null;
    private Path customersPath = null;
    private File customersFile = null;

public CustomerTextFile(){

    customersPath = Paths.get("customers.txt");
    customersFile = customersPath.toFile();
    customers = this.getCustomers();

}
@Override
public Customer getCustomer(String emailAddress) {
    for (Customer c : customers) {
        if (c.getEmail().equals(emailAddress))
                return c;
    }
    return null;

    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public ArrayList<Customer> getCustomers() {
    if (customers != null)
        return customers;

    customers = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!Files.exists(customersPath)) {
        try {
            Files.createFile(customersPath);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    if (Files.exists(customersPath)) {
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(customersFile))){
            String line = in.readLine();
            while(line != null) {
                String[] columns = line.split("\t");
                String email = columns[0];
                String firstName = columns[1];
                String lastName = columns[2];

                Customer c = new Customer(email, firstName, lastName);
                customers.add(c);

            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    return customers;
}

@Override
public boolean addCustomer(Customer c) {
    customers.add(c);
    return this.saveCustomers();
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public boolean updateCustomer(Customer c) {
    Customer oldCustomer = this.getCustomer(c.getEmail());
    int i = customers.indexOf(oldCustomer);
    customers.remove(i);

    customers.add(i, c);

    return this.saveCustomers();
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public boolean deleteCustomer(Customer c) {
    customers.remove(c);
    return this.saveCustomers();
}

private boolean saveCustomers() {
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(customersFile)))){

        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            out.print(customer.getEmail() + "\t");
            out.print(customer.getFirstName() + "\t");
            out.println(customer.getLastName());

        }
        out.close();
        return true;

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }



}
```

}

Im not certain if the problem is in the application or if it is in the textfile class

> run:
>   Welcome to the Customer Maintenance application

COMMAND MENU
list    - List all customers
add     - Add a customer
del     - Delete a customer
help    - Show this menu
exit    - Exit this application

list
DEBUG LINE 1

Above was an example of the console output.

Comment: Is it every action that causes the program to stop? And does it actually stop, as in terminated, or does it stay alive. The later would mean an infinate loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring a string inside the loop?

try this instead:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String userChoice;
do {
    displayMenu();
    userChoice = sc.nextLine(); //takes in the entire lien you type in
    System.out.println("DEBUG LINE 1");


    CustomerTextFile textFile = new CustomerTextFile();
    System.out.println("DEBUG LINE 2");
    performAction(userChoice, textFile);
    System.out.println("DEBUG LINE 3");
} while(keepGoing);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The strings declaration position shouldn't matter in this situation since that's more an issue of scope in Java.

Comment: Yeah. I tried it anyway for efficiency but the problem still exixts